# How to create a new line in a confirmation dialog in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dialog

So I have a confirmation dialog below which warns the user each time he click the button, but what I want is to create a new line after the question, and insert the note.

```
this.$dialog.confirm("Create Group","Would you like to create group "+ this.groupName +"?<br/>(NOTE: Selected project or employee/s will be automatically assigned to this group.)")
```

The result is below:

[image]

My `<br/>` is interpreted as text. I also have tried `/n` but also doesn't work, it's just replaced by a single space character.

Comment: Did you try `\n`? You might need to add css `white-space:pre`

Comment: @ittus Yep, but doesn't work as well. Same attitude with `/n`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the vuejs-dialog plugin's readme page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-dialog),

You can set the option's `html` to true so that `<br>` will work

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/kyabo054/2/

e.g.

```
this.$dialog.confirm('Please confirm to continue<br>NextLine', {        
  html: true      
})
```

Comment: It's still interpreted as text :S